# Use Stream to read private key

Tags: c#, stream, private-key, mailkit, dkim

**UPDATE WITH A READER for more inside:**

This works:

```
var privateKeyPath = @"C:\foo\DKIM Private Key.txt";
var signer = new DkimSigner(
    privateKeyPath, 
    mailKitConfiguration.Domain, 
    mailKitConfiguration.Selector);
signer.Sign(message, headersToSign);
```

How can it work using Stream instead? - I don't even know if it's my `privateKey` variable or my `memory Stream` that is causing my troubles. I've tried this:

```
var privateKey = @"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MICESDABCDEF..............KBgQDa3-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
var privateKeyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(privateKey);
using (var memory = new MemoryStream(privateKeyBytes))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory))
    {
        var test1 = reader.ReadLine(); // test1: "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICXQIBAAKBgQDa38lnCp4wTcuk0Dkl6zjbc9hkeTCLFa0F4pc7XCsDj......."
        var test2 = reader.ReadLine(); // test2: empty
        var test3 = reader.ReadLine(); // test3: empty
    }

    memory.Position = 0;

    var signer = new DkimSigner(
        memory, 
        mailKitConfiguration.Domain, 
        mailKitConfiguration.Selector
    );
    signer.Sign(message, headersToSign);
}
```

Message:

```
System.FormatException: Private key not found.
```

Stacktrace:

```
at MimeKit.Cryptography.DkimSignerBase.LoadPrivateKey(Stream stream)
at MimeKit.Cryptography.DkimSigner..ctor(Stream stream, String domain, String selector, 
DkimSignatureAlgorithm algorithm)
```

Comment: @jdweng Still got the same error. I've also updated the code. You mean like this right? I'm new to Streams.

Comment: When I debug, the Position is already "0" before "memory.Position = 0;".

Comment: The memory stream position is moved to the end of data after a write.  Then if you read all you get is the EOS.  You must move the position to zero before reading (after the write).  The memory stream is also not valid outside the using block.

Comment: Ok it make sense, but I not sure what exactly what line you mean. Do you mean like this, where I added `memory.Position = 0;` between the using open bracket and before `var signer...`? Because I've tried that with no luck. Is it something else?

Comment: After following : var memory = new MemoryStream(privateKeyBytes)

Comment: At this point I might be a little suspicious that you have a valid private key. How was this pem file created?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It's valid, I've send over 50 mails the last weeks. That's why I provided my working solution, to rule it out. I think the problem is bytes isn't chunked in small pieces like they are on each line in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reset the stream's position to 0, the constructor `MemoryStream(byte[])` already starts at 0.

You need newline characters in your key: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n(data)\r\n---`.

Comment: Ok I'll try. That was my first thought by when I googled it, someone said this wouldn't work, so I actually never tried it.

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error. I've tried both with and without "\n" at the very end for the long string as I was not sure to include it.

Comment: Yes, the PemReader expects the PEM format key to be in a certain format: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/bc3b92f1f0e78b82e2584c5fb4b226a13e7f8b3b/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemReader.java#L46 which would only work if line breaks, as suggested, are included

Comment: Okay cool, I'll delete the last `\n`. I only tried it, because the first try didn't do the trick. Maybe I need `\r\n` instead? I will go through all of my `\n` 's again, but they should be in the right place.

Comment: @CodeCaster Do you think it could be anything else, e.g. like the `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(privateKey)`? :/

Comment: @radbyx well the StreamReader used within the code assumes UTF-8, which is a superset of ASCII, so that should just work, as you only use characters that lie within the ASCII codepoint range. You can test your input and output by using a `StreamReader(memory)` and calling ReadLine three times. And only **after** reading or writing you need to reset its position.

Comment: @CodeCaster Please see my update, the reader shows the "\n" doesn't work. :/

Comment: @radbyx that's because you're defining a @verbatim string. You don't need the `@`.